# How to make an array like [[123][234][345]] using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like 

`[1,3,4,5,6,2,1,,,,]`

now, I want to change it to 

`[[1,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,6],[5,6,2],,,,]`

How can I achieve this using numpy? Is there any function to do so? And, using loop is not an option.

Comment: Is that really an array, or just a list?  And how big?  What are you going to do with the result?  There is an array method using `stride_tricks`, but that's for 'advanced users'.

Answer (score 2):

[np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/) method will does that.

> Here strides is (4,4) for 32 bit int. If you want more flexible code, I have commented stride parameter in the code. shape parameter determines output array dimensions.

```
> import numpy as np
> A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
> n = 3 # output matrix has 3 columns
> m = len(A) - (n-1) # calculate number of output matrix rows using input matrix length
> # strides_param = np.array(A, dtype=np.int32).strides * 2
> np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(A, shape=(m,n), strides=(4,4))
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: @beroe I edited the answer with output

Comment: Your sublists don't overlap.

Comment: @hpaulj I modified the code

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension instead of a library but why make it complicated. (Do you consider this a loop?)

```
x = [1,3,4,5,6,2,1]
y = [x[n:n+3] for n in range(len(x)-2)]
```

Result is:

```
[[1, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 2], [6, 2, 1]]
```